# Check if user has voted on a post

Tags: c#, database-design

I'm creating a voting system for posts on my blog-like website.

Each post will have a rating, stored in the database. A user can click to upvote or downvote and the number in the database will increase or decrease. Simple stuff.

But how would I check if the current user has already voted?

My initial thoughts were to create two additional columns in the database for each post, "UsersUp" and "UsersDown", storing the usernames of those that have voted up and voted down for each post. I'd check if the username exists and if it does, the vote would be removed rather than another vote being added.
I could even remove the "rating" column altogether and achieve the same thing by just counting the number of usernames in UsersUp and subtracting the number of usernames in UsersDown.

Am I approaching this in the wrong way?

I'm not asking for any code, just the theory behind how i'd achieve this.

I need users not to be able to vote up or down twice, and they would need to be able to retract their vote by clicking again.

Comment: If you want to minimize the need to do joins and heavy queries ("simple stuff") you should put a lock on the logged-in user for each post that they already casted the vote. Then your vote aggregation should just make sure that this lock is not present when the vote is cast before it does a `+1` or `-1`.

Comment: Would i do this in the posts table, or in the users table? Can you be more specific? Would i store the usernames with the posts and then query them?

Comment: You are on the right track but don't have 2 columns for up & down, you just need a single bit column. In fact see how Stackoverflow do it using the DataExplorer https://data.stackexchange.com, it has the db schema

Comment: So how would I "connect" the username to the post id? I've read about one-to-many data models, is that what i'd need? I hope you understand what i'm confused about. Where/how would i keep record of the usernames/IDs/IPs of people who have voted on a post?  
Also, I didn't know about this (the link), thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a [normalized database design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

You probably have a `User` table, and based on the question, you have a `Post` table.

You can represent the relationship between users, posts, and their votes with a third `UserVote` table. This allows granular tracking of who voted, when, and how they voted (VoteTypeId could contain the ID of an upvote or downvote).

```
+--------+--------+------------+----------+
| UserId | PostId | VoteTypeId | VoteDate |
+--------+--------+------------+----------+
|    1   |    1   |      1     | 1/1/2017 |
+--------+--------+------------+----------+
|    2   |    1   |      1     | 2/1/2017 |
+--------+--------+------------+----------+
|    3   |    1   |      2     | 2/2/2017 |
+--------+--------+------------+----------+
```

This models the data. How should you call it from c#?

```
if( !HasVoted( userId, postId ) ){
    SaveVote( userId, postId, voteTypeId );
    UpdateVoteCount( postId, voteTypeId );
}
```

However, this is very error-prone. What if `UpdateVoteCount()` fails?

There are multiple ways to approach this, among them:

- Aggregate vote counts when you need them (don't store them).
- Wrap the operation in a transaction.

```
using( var scope = new TransactionScope() ){    
    if( !HasVoted( userId, postId ) ){
        SaveVote( userId, postId, voteTypeId );
        UpdateVoteCount( postId, voteTypeId );
    }

    scope.Complete();
}
```

Read More: [TransactionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx)

That helps with data integrity, but the code still has a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) which allows the system to be abused.

We need a lock around the entire operation. One way to accomplish this is with the stored procedure `sp_getapplock` which allows you to block on a named resource until the holder of the lock releases it.

You could use a single named lock, or you could lock per item (tricky if voting on one item might have broader consequences like reputation calculation).

Read More: [sp_getapplock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql)

Our sequence becomes:

1. Take a named lock.
2. Start a transaction.
3. Check that the user hasn't already voted.
4. Register the vote.
5. Update other values (e.g. total vote count, user reputation gains).
6. Commit the transaction.
7. Release the lock.

While this sounds complicated and the lock sounds like it would be a bottleneck, it actually performs well. I stress-tested this design several years ago and easily achieved throughput of 2500+ vote operations per second.

The calling code should ensure that:

- the locks taken have a short timeout
- that transactions are committed/rolled back even if an exception is thrown.
- the lock is disposed of even if an exception is thrown.

Comment: Wow, great answer. A lot of it went over my head but i'll be sure to read the links you provided.  
Learning this stuff is very demotivating sometimes as things are always harder than I imagine them to be. Any advise (as someone clearly adept regarding this stuff) would be appreciated :)  

Why did you choose to save the vote count and then update the count?  
I presume that SaveVote will write to the database, and UpdateVoteCount will use AJAX to update the page?

Comment: Ah, the question I asked above is answered in the second part of your answer, i just overlooked it at first.

Comment: It *is* complicated but usually someone has solved the problem before and/or there is a tool to make it easier. It's helpful to know what terms to look for, e.g. "normalization".

Comment: Incidentally, you could write the entire save process as a single stored procedure in the database. The stored procedure could take a lock, create a transaction, and perform all updates. You'd then call it from c# as needed.

Comment: I watched some videos on Normalization and i understand the first three normalization forms, so thanks for that. Regarding locks and transactions, i've not heard of these before this post, are they important and necessary? Do you have a more visual learning aid for these things?

Comment: For transactions managed from c#, look at the link for `TransactionScope` I mentioned. For transactions in managed inside T-SQL code, read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-transaction-transact-sql. It's actually simple; you begin a transaction and either commit it or roll it back. SQL Server will ensure that the transaction either succeeds or all work is rolled back. Locking is a complex subject, but sp_getapplock (link in my answer) lets the database handle that. Just make sure to release the lock or you'll block other callers.

Comment: Oh wow that sounds extremely useful, and well explained, thank you.  
I found an explanation of applock here, https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic896919-360-1.aspx and here, https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3202/prevent-multiple-users-from-running-the-same-sql-server-stored-procedure-at-the-same-time/